# Hive 'Expression Not in Group By Key' Error

Tags: group-by, hive, hiveql, sql-like

I created a table in hdfs with the following columns:

```
word_id string, word_name string, word_synonym string
```

I want to use LIKE command to get the count of how many times a word appears in word_synonym

```
SELECT word_synonym, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE word_synonym LIKE '%abcd%';
```

Running this in MySQL, I get the correct output, however in Hive I get the following error:

```
SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'word_synonym'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by operation. when you use an aggregate function, you have to represent "group by" operation in your query.

`SELECT word_synonym, COUNT(word_synonym) FROM table WHERE word_synonym LIKE '%abcd%' group by word_synonym;`

This query doesn't give the count of '%abcd%' statement. Because when query is performed, where cause is worked first after that grouping process is started based on the final record. You should pay attention to the execution order of SQL operations [link](https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/).

PS: if you want to get how many records exist based on your like condition, I need to use a subquery.